PowerShell stops Windows from launching because it can't run a script
I did some experiments who I thought were safe with PowerShell, but unfortunately after shutting down and launching windows 10 again, it asks for a program to launch a "-shell" shortcut (like the one that appears when you open a file without a liked app) but with no options. If I close the pop-up the screen remains black.
I have access to Ctrl+alt+canc and the block screen.
Do you have any ideas? Thanks.
I tried launching in safe mode but it doesn't change anything.
Neither rebooting the system helps.
I don't have a recovery point.

I'm assuming Ctrl+alt+canc is the same as ctrl + alt + del. If you are that far into Windows where you can access that menu, try launching task manager and going to File > Run. In the box that opens type explorer.exe and hit OK. If that works it should load your desktop/taskbar etc.
